# Date range on elasticsearch returns too many results

Tags: php, date, elasticsearch

I've a problem using the date range. I have the following code snippet:

```
const ISO8601_FROM = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s+1200';
const ISO8601_TO = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s-1200';

$dateRange = new RangeBuilder();
if ($this->filterDateFrom instanceof \DateTime) {
    $dateRange->from($this->filterDateFrom
        ->setTime(0, 0, 0)
        ->format(self::ISO8601_FROM)
    );
}
if ($this->filterDateTo instanceof \DateTime) {
    $dateRange->to($this->filterDateTo
        ->setTime(23, 59, 59)
        ->format(self::ISO8601_TO)
    );
}
if ($dateRange->isValid()) {
    $boolQuery->addMust(new Range('dateCreate', $dateRange->buildRange()));
}
```

The part of the json string my RangeBuilder will return is:

```
"range" : {
    "dateCreate" : {
        "gte" : "2000-01-01T00:00:00+1200",
        "lte" : "2000-01-01T23:59:59-1200"
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to get results from the 1st of January.
My problem is now that I also get documents for the 2nd of January.

Because the _mapping is a bit extensive, I will only post the beginning of the block:

```
{"myindex":{"mappings":{"tdo":{"properties":{"author":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"client":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"content":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"dateCreate":{"type":"date"},"documents":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},...
```

Comment: What is the type of `dateCreate` field? Please check it in your index mapping.

Comment: It's of type "date".

Comment: Okay, Have you tried with the date format given in [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)?

Comment: I tried it with "yyyy-MM-dd" but with the same effect.

Comment: Why using a range ? If you just want one day you can do an equal with the format yyyy-mm-dd no ?

Comment: The problem is that my search uses selection from a date picker so it depends on the user if the query is executed only with one day or with one week etc. So I have to use a range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not use the same time zone in query and index mapping.

Post your mapping info and one of response's hit you do not want to get may help more.

Comment: Do your every doc has “+1200” in `dateCreate` field. (By the way, I guess the part `"lte" : "2000-01-01T23:59:59-1200"` has a handwriting error)

Comment: Hm, your right. It seems that not every document has the +1200 offset. Is there a possibility to get these documents anyway?

Comment: You can use script query seems like `doc['dateCreate'].length() < 24`.